# Nodejs express es6 dotenv file loading after controller load

Tags: node.js, express, es6-class

I load dotenv module in app.js in my node application. I need to call .env attributes inside constructor classes. When I call process.env.ATTRIBUTE it always say undefined. When I look closely I noticed that constructors(JS classes) invoking first before the app.js invoke. How I can make those attribute available in constructor class in order to use them.

Comment: please add code example